# Ubuntu20.04 libhdf5.so.8 and libH5Part.so.0 not found

Tags: server, compiling

I compiled `hdf5` and `h5part` in ubuntu 20.04, linked them inside `makefile` and `\etc\profile`. But when I run `mpirun -np 4 lapine lapine.inp`, error appears as below

```
proxy:0:0@ubuntu] HYDU_create_process (utils/launch/launch.c:74): execvp error on file lapine (No such file or directory)
```

Then I typed `ldd lapine`, the message is

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff62411000)
libhdf5.so.8 => not found
libH5Part.so.0 => not found
libmpi.so.12 => /opt/mpich3/lib/libmpi.so.12 (0x00007f55ab5b9000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f55ab3d7000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f55ab288000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f55ab26d000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f55ab079000)
libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f55ab056000)
librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f55ab04c000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f55aba69000)
```

it seems that `hdf5` and `h5part` are not linked correctly. After checking several times, I still could not fix it. Could any one help me out? Thx.

`hdf5` configure parameters

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/hdf5 --enable-parallel --with-pic --enable-linux-lfs --enable-shared --enable-build-mode=production --disable-sharedlib-rpath --enable-static --with-szlib=/opt/szip --with-zlib=/opt/zlib CC=/opt/mpich3/bin/mpicc CXX=/opt/mpich3/bin/mpicxx
```

`h5part` configure parameters

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/H5part --enable-parallel --with-pic --enable-shared --enable-build-mode=production --disable-sharedlib-rpath --enable-static --with-hdf5=/opt/hdf5 CC=/opt/mpich3/bin/mpicc CXX=/opt/mpich3/bin/mpicxx
```

`\etc\profile`:

```
export PATH=/opt/mpich3/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/opt/hdf5/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/hdf5/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/H5part/lib
```

`\lapine\src\makefile`:

```
 CXX = /opt/mpich3/bin/mpicxx
 ....

 MPIHOME=/opt/mpich3
 HDF5HOME= /opt/hdf5
 H5PARTHOME= /opt/H5part
 BLITZHOME= /usr/local/include/blitz
 SZIPHOME= /opt/szip
 ZLIBHOME= /opt/zlib

 INCS = -I$(HDF5HOME)/include    -I$(BLITZHOME)/include    
 -I$(SZIPHOME)/include   -I$(ZLIBHOME)/include  -I$(H5PARTHOME)/include

 LIBS = -L$(BLITZHOME)/lib -lblitz -L$(SZIPHOME)/lib -lsz 
 -L$(ZLIBHOME)/lib -lz  -L$(HDF5HOME)/lib -lhdf5 -lz -lsz 
 -L$(H5PARTHOME)/lib -lH5Part -lz -ldl

 OBJECTS = main.o readfile.o oerror.o sobol.o parameter.o network.o \
      field.o domain.o fieldsolver.o boundaryEB.o boundaryP.o  \
```

sixpenny

Comment: Hello! welcome to AskUbuntu! what command do you run to `compile`; and with what `parameters?` As well as ; do you think you can link to the download/source/repo where you got it so I can try myself; to replicate it :)

Comment: Thanks William. I use `configure/make` to compile and have added the parameters for `hdf5` and `h5part` in the question. I wonder whether the version of `hdf5` matters. And what do you mean by linking to the `download/source/repo`?

Comment: I mean where did you get the program you are trying to download? :),  github? if so, paste github link!  gitlab? gitlab link! :) so I can download it and try to compile it myself; have a good one!

Comment: The programe of `lapine` is written by another guy, not commercial. Others are free.

Comment: Solved this problem just by restarting ubuntu... Took me several days!!! But when I run `./lapine`, new error `c++ readfile::set get: keyword @plasma missing`. Confusing...

Comment: then make a answer yourself and accept it;  saying the solution :)

Comment: and search for the new erorr then  if not found  ask a new question :)

Comment: Have solved by refreshing the file after decompressing it again and make. The reason might be that the part of the file is changed by me unconsciously. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you needed to `make clean` or `diff` some files; (can be worth to keep in mind for the future; which is why I  comment with that)  nice it solved itself! make a new answer and; accept it :)